# Why numpy.sum does not give me the right result?

Tags: python, list, numpy, sum

The sum of a standard python list say x=list(range(100000)) does not coincide with a sum of the same sequence  x_array=np.array(x). In the first case I obtain sum(x)=4999950000, which is the correct result. Using numpy sum I obtain np.sum(x_array))=704982704.  This troubles me because i am a beginner with this language. Does anyone have an explanation for this difference? Thank you. The code is

```
import numpy as np
x=list(range(100000))
print("sum x using standard python function = ",sum(x))
x_array=np.array(x)
print("sum x using numpy =",np.sum(x_array))
```

Comment: The methodology is correct; try it for range = 100 and you'll see it works just fine. As mentioned below, there's a difference in how NumPy handles certain data.

Comment: What version of python and numpy are you using? An upgrade will probably fix this. Failing that `x_array = np.array(x, dtype='int64')`

Comment: If a use x_array = np.array(x, dtype='int64') I get the right result! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your NumPy defaults to standard 32-bit integers; Python will switch to indefinitely long integers as needed.

You got bitten by overflow/wraparound.

```
4999950000 % (2**32)   ==>   704982704
```

Comment: Which versions does your answer refer to? running the code on python 3.7.3 yields the same results for both methods

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32